# React app not working with react-query and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

am trying to use React-query and TypeScript in my React application but it not working, am get an Error: react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. i think the problem is from the latest upgrade.  please could the error be coming from.

Here's my code

index file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
 
 const queryClient = new QueryClient()

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
).render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      GetStarted
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you mean react 18.2 upgrade? I was just about to upgrade react-query project too.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox? The code in these two files seems fine, but somewhere you are using a hook outside of a function component as the error states.

Comment: yes, just noticed the upgrade

Comment: @MrUnknown is working fine, if dont add the React-query library

Comment: then please show this in a codesandbox reproduction :)

Answer (score -1):

try to warp elements in `App` component, like that.

```js
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'

export default function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <div className="App">Hello</div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: sorry but this is wrong. Creating a new QueryClient during rendering of the App can lead to various issues, like throwing the cache away after a render. You need to have a "stable" client!